# How to update custom specific UITableview cell in storyboard, which are dynamically generated?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboard

I am developing my first app in objective-c. In first view controller I am able to generate UITableview with dynamic prototype cells containing accessory button. When I click on the accessory button, it will navigate to next view controller, which would also having dynamic UITableviewcells with (Custom button)Select as accessory button. But, when I click on the specific select button, corresponding cell contents should be updated in the cell(In first screen) for which accessory button is clicked. I am able to get the details from the second screen to first screen. But, my custom cell in the first screen is not updating?

Please help whether there is any pre-defined function, which I've not found in the reference doc.

Thankyou in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution algoritm come from beginning ios 5 development.

1.Take the indexPath in prepareSegue

```
// prepare selection info
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
```

2.Send that to second view controller

```
    UIViewController *destination = segue.destinationViewController;
    [destination setValue:self forKey:@"delegate"];

    id object = [self.tasks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSDictionary *selection = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:indexPath,@"indexPath",object,@"object", nil];        
    [destination setValue:selection forKey:@"selection"];
```

3.The second view controller later will **send back the indexPath** to the first controller

```
// prepare selection info back
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_selection objectForKey:@"indexPath"];
id object = _textView.text;
NSDictionary *editedSelection = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:indexPath, @"indexPath", object, @"object", nil];
[_delegate setValue:editedSelection forKey:@"editedSelection"];
```

4.So in the **getter method** of first view controller which used to **take the indexPath back** from the secomd view controller, you take back the table cell by indexPath and change its value

```
#pragma mark - Call back by destination view
-(void)setEditedSelection:(NSDictionary *)dict{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [dict objectForKey:@"indexPath"];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    ....
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for reply, can you please give me a prototype how can I accomplish this...

Comment: I am sorry. I replied this post on the mobile phone.
I should give you some examples:) wait..I will edit my answer

Comment: Hi @code4j, in the above the indexpath values are changing while scrolling uitableview. How can I overcame that...